# Documenting jQuery using JSDoc

Tags: javascript, jquery, documentation, jsdoc

I've recently started using JSDoc for documentation. I'm trying to document my JS codes that uses jQuery to grabs a class in HTML and performs an action defined by an anonymous function:

```
$(".crop-img").click(function(){
    $("#bigImg").attr('src',
        $(this).attr('src'));
});
```

What JSDoc tags do you recommend to use?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly is the asnwer

```
/**
* Large image is shown when thumbnail is clicked
* @author Armin
* @name bigImg
*/
$(".crop-img").click(function(){
    $("#bigImg").attr('src',
    $(this).attr('src'));
});
```